# Terraform for Cloudfront: InvalidHeadersForS3Origin, but I'm not passing [*] to any S3 origin

Tags: wordpress, terraform, amazon-cloudfront, terraform-provider-aws

Running terraform 1.0.8 on Windows, trying to configure AWS Cloudfront.  I'm using state managed in S3.

My config has several origins and many behaviors all for one distribution.  When I run `terraform apply`, I get the following error:

```
│ Error: error updating CloudFront Distribution (E2KIMIP81FA3TQ): InvalidHeadersForS3Origin: Your request contains forwarded Header Name * that is not allowed by S3.
│       status code: 400, request id: ac0ad34e-7208-46a2-9334-e55465391028
│
│   with aws_cloudfront_distribution.web-distribution,
│   on cloudfront.tf line 129, in resource "aws_cloudfront_distribution" "web-distribution":
│  129: resource "aws_cloudfront_distribution" "web-distribution" {
```

But I've reviewed my .tf file many times and although I have some origins in S3, and some behaviors passing [*] for the headers, there are no cases where I'm passing [*] to an S3 origin.  All of my behaviors passing wildcard headers are pointing to a Wordpress origin.

What could I be missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed!

I inserted `headers = [ ]` in behaviors where there was no headers node.